# Prevent login based on user role - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have just added a new column [role_id] in Laravel default users table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddRolesidToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('role_id');
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know where in Laravel can i add the validation rule for a user to login?

For example if a user doesn't have a required role_id he can't login even though he is in the database!
So the idea is that admin should first activate the account so the user could login.

Comment: Can you post your roles table structure and eloquent models as well?

Comment: I don't have roles table, and the user model table is default, only with this added column...i just started the project. So i think this should be done somewhere in login process. I need just to add one more validation rule beside username and password - but where is this login validation?

Comment: I finally found it....the function login is in this file: /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

Comment: You should not edit anything in the **vendor** folder because it will be overwritten. Instead overwrite the **login()** method in your **AuthController** which is in the app folder.

Comment: but this is more complicated than i thought...maybe i should have ask how to implement user activation in laravel so that user can login only if he is activated???

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you to edit the core Laravel files. Instead include Role through your code. Your can check the Sentry Sentinel package which has great functionality.

Comment: See the [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users) section in the docs. We can specify additional conditions on authentication.

Comment: what are the possible values of `role_id` ? Is it foreign key ?

Comment: no it's just another column in users table

Comment: @haitran this is an answer to my question....make it as answer so i can thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users) section in the docs. We can specify additional conditions on authentication:

`if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}`